# iptables service is not recognized

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS6 image deployed in Azure. This is an image available in Azure and I used this image to deploy a VM in Azure.

I'm trying to allow port 5901 in iptables but for some reason, I get the message '`status: unrecognized service`' when I run the command `service status iptables` .

There is no `/etc/init.d/iptables` file either.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `iptables` and `iptables-services` are installed with

```
rpm -qa | grep iptables
```

If not, you have to install it before using with:

```
yum install iptables iptables-services
```

Comment: iptables is installed and I am also able to see the rules when I run iptables -L

Comment: `iptables-services` then. I updated my answer